# como realizar la siguiente consulta en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy realizando una consulta en la cual estoy filtrando en un rango de fecha y filtrando con like el filtro lo toma perfecto pero no en el rango de fecha estipulado la funcion es la siguiente:

```
public function ventasdisenoFiltro(Request $request){

    $fecha1=$request->fecha1;
    $fecha2=$request->fecha2;

    $diseno=DB::table('dcargos')
    ->whereBetween('DEFECO', array($request->fecha1,$request->fecha2))
    ->where('DECODI', 'LIKE', "la%" ,'or','DECODI', 'LIKE', "%1199300%",'or','DECODI', 'LIKE', "%gra0700%")
    ->where('DETIPO', '!=' , '3')
    ->get();

    return view('admin.ventasdiseno',compact('diseno'));
```

la consulta en mysql es la siguiente y si me funciona bien:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    dcargos
WHERE
    DEFECO BETWEEN "2021-07-01" AND "2021-07-28"
        AND detipo != '3' and (DECODI LIKE 'la%'
        OR DECODI LIKE '%1199300%'
        OR DECODI LIKE '%gra0700%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento que la sintaxis que empleas en el método [**`where`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses) no es la adecuada pues dicho método puede recibir como argumentos:

- column
- operator
- value
- boolean

Puedes revisar esto en: *Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder*, luego entonces si requieres [agrupar en paréntesis](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses) varias condiciones, deberás pasarlos dentro de un *closure*

```
$diseno=DB::table('dcargos')
->whereBetween('DEFECO', array($request->fecha1,$request->fecha2))
->where('DETIPO', '!=' , '3')
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('DECODI', 'LIKE', 'la%')
        ->orWhere('DECODI', 'LIKE', '%1199300%')
        ->orWhere('DECODI', 'LIKE', '%gra0700%');
})->get();
```

Comment: gracias me funciono de manera correcta